# Open-source PSNR/ SSIM C implementation without OpenCV?

Tags: c, algorithm, open-source, video-processing, ssim

Is there any open source C implementation for PSNR, SSIM or MSE that doesn't rely on OpenCV?

Thanks.

Comment: openCV is BSD licensed so you can just take the implementation from it's source and modify it for your needs

Comment: @Martin Beckett: Yes, you are right, but I don't want to be dependant on external 3rd party libraries. Thank you anyway.

Comment: I meant just cut and paste the code straight from the OpenCV source into your code - no library needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IQA](http://tdistler.com/iqa/index.html) provides a C implementation with no dependencies of the following image quality metrics:

- MSE
- PSNR
- SSIM
- MS-SSIM
- MS-SSIM*

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

Google's WebM project provides these calculations in the [libvpx library](http://review.webmproject.org/gitweb?p=libvpx.git).  Specifically in the [VP8 encoder](http://review.webmproject.org/gitweb?p=libvpx.git;a=tree;f=vp8/encoder;hb=HEAD).

Then there is also [NetPBM](https://netpbm.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/netpbm/trunk/analyzer/), [FFMPEG](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=blob;f=tests/tiny_psnr.c;hb=HEAD) and the [x264 Project](http://git.videolan.org/?p=x264.git;a=blob;f=common/pixel.c;hb=HEAD).